# Error when trying to create an adobe object on another machine

Tags: c#, exception, adobe

I have an application which allows me to display pdf thumbnails. I am using this line of code

```
pdfDoc = (Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc)Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc", "");
```

The thing is, on my development machine it works, when i create an installer and install on my machine, it works but as soon as another machine has it installed it fails at this line.

If it was a problem with the installer then i assume when i installed it on my machine it would fail to run properly. Can someone help me out as to what the issues potentially might be?

My log file states this when users on another machine try and run the application

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{9B4CD3E7-4981-101B-9CA8-9240CE2738AE}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would started with trying to install Acrobat(appropriate version, of course) separately on that machine where you have issue. And then I would run application again to see if error still exists... In such way you will know if issue is in installer...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error you described.  Try running Acrobat from the Start Menu and see if it starts normally.

I ran Acrobat (from the start menu) and for a reason I ignore, an Installer (msiexec) started. Once the installation/update was done, Acrobat started.  I closed Acrobat and re-started the app from the start menu and the application started normally.  Once that was "resolved", I was able to run my .net application.

I'm not sure if it's related, but in the Event Logs, I had this entry:

Faulting application Acrobat.exe, version 10.0.0.396, time stamp 0x4cc5ebc0, faulting module Acrobat.dll, version 10.0.0.396, time stamp 0x4cc5f7e2, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x00d34c3c, process id 0x2168, application start time 0x01ce092635390c31.